# How long should I cook a 1 lb pork sirloin roast?

Tags: pork, roasting

I was given a 1 lb pork sirloin roast, but no instructions about cooking it! I want to roast it in the oven, but the charts say 20 minutes per lb. That doesn't sound right to me. What do I do? TIA

Comment: Recipe recommendations are off topic on this site. Everyone has a favourite way of cooking a roast. In general you will get the best result from using a meat thermometer and cooking to a set temperature rather than cooking by time.

Comment: I don't know if I'd count this as a recipe request, we answer questions about how long to cook things all the time

Comment: I think this answer in particular might help you out! https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/49756/17272